# Make SVG fit to 100vw

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make this SVG fit to 100vw, but I can't seem to make it happen.

I've tried adding a class and playing with width: 100vw.
I've tried adding a viewBox="0 0 900 1135" (and attempted to change the attributes, but it never works).

I have a CodePen for it and would appreciate any ideas on how to make this SVG look the same on any screen size.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/superwebdigital/pen/oNObdBG

```css
body {background-color:black}
```

```html
<body>
<svg width='100vw' height="1135" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    
<g filter="url(#filter0_bi_771_414)">
<path d="M1923 3.0437C1886.27 11.4761 1847.41 24.1602 1806.36 41.7532C1695.81 89.1314 1613.3 134.288 1541.57 173.544C1299.46 306.054 1180.21 371.321 519.999 227.797C308.659 181.853 138.487 163.464 3 165.423V1124.05C144.84 1149.69 331.446 1116.75 578.468 982.601C1003.51 751.782 1509.05 883.186 1923 1001.07V3.0437Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_771_414)" fill-opacity="0.74"/>
<path d="M1924.14 3.0437V1.61733L1922.75 1.93648C1885.94 10.3854 1847.02 23.0916 1805.91 40.709C1695.31 88.1087 1612.76 133.287 1541.04 172.544L1541.03 172.548C1419.97 238.804 1329.81 288.14 1187.46 303.053C1045.04 317.973 850.327 298.445 520.241 226.687C308.843 180.73 138.581 162.326 2.98357 164.288L1.86397 164.304V165.423V1124.05V1125L2.79792 1125.17C144.986 1150.87 331.862 1117.81 579.01 983.6C1003.58 753.036 1508.66 884.255 1922.69 1002.16L1924.14 1002.58V1001.07V3.0437Z" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_771_414)" stroke-width="2.27205" />
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_bi_771_414" x="-50.5211" y="-51.0577" width="2027.04" height="1236.65" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="25.6243"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur_771_414"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_771_414" result="shape"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dx="2.56243" dy="5.12487"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.8122"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect2_innerShadow_771_414"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_771_414" x1="1905.21" y1="-1521.1" x2="-2512.19" y2="453.891" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.08"/>
<stop offset="0.494792" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.825"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.35"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear_771_414" x1="3051.67" y1="-641.335" x2="1738.45" y2="2781.39" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
<stop offset="0.567961" stop-color="white"/>
<stop offset="0.946343" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
<body>
```

Comment: You will need to add a viewBox attribute. Please try `viewBox="1.8 1.6 1923 1132"`. Also I would like to ask why do you need the height="1135".

Comment: the `viewbox` is used to delimit a surface useful for vector drawing, that is to say without using real units such as pixels or a relation to a screen dimension.
The properies `with` and `height` values are used to give a real display dimension, that is to say with unit values. if the proportions of the with/height and those of the viewbox do not match, then the image may or may not be distorted, depending on the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute

Comment: I received an alert that this worked for you, but I don't see it anywhere. If it helped, please accept the answer in case someone happens upon this and can try it for themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `viewbox` to define it's position and dimension inside the SVG viewport, otherwise it can act quite funny: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox.

Optionally, you can also use `preserveAspectRatio="none"` for full control of the aspect ratio of the svg. Use this if you need to confine the whole shape inside a div: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
  margin:0;
}
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg width='100vw' height="1135" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1924.14 1133.53" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    
<g filter="url(#filter0_bi_771_414)">
<path d="M1923 3.0437C1886.27 11.4761 1847.41 24.1602 1806.36 41.7532C1695.81 89.1314 1613.3 134.288 1541.57 173.544C1299.46 306.054 1180.21 371.321 519.999 227.797C308.659 181.853 138.487 163.464 3 165.423V1124.05C144.84 1149.69 331.446 1116.75 578.468 982.601C1003.51 751.782 1509.05 883.186 1923 1001.07V3.0437Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_771_414)" fill-opacity="0.74"/>
<path d="M1924.14 3.0437V1.61733L1922.75 1.93648C1885.94 10.3854 1847.02 23.0916 1805.91 40.709C1695.31 88.1087 1612.76 133.287 1541.04 172.544L1541.03 172.548C1419.97 238.804 1329.81 288.14 1187.46 303.053C1045.04 317.973 850.327 298.445 520.241 226.687C308.843 180.73 138.581 162.326 2.98357 164.288L1.86397 164.304V165.423V1124.05V1125L2.79792 1125.17C144.986 1150.87 331.862 1117.81 579.01 983.6C1003.58 753.036 1508.66 884.255 1922.69 1002.16L1924.14 1002.58V1001.07V3.0437Z" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_771_414)" stroke-width="2.27205"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_bi_771_414" x="-50.5211" y="-51.0577" width="2027.04" height="1236.65" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="25.6243"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur_771_414"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_771_414" result="shape"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dx="2.56243" dy="5.12487"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.8122"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect2_innerShadow_771_414"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_771_414" x1="1905.21" y1="-1521.1" x2="-2512.19" y2="453.891" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.08"/>
<stop offset="0.494792" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.825"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.35"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear_771_414" x1="3051.67" y1="-641.335" x2="1738.45" y2="2781.39" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
<stop offset="0.567961" stop-color="white"/>
<stop offset="0.946343" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
<body>
```